# inserting custom block next to each item in checkout cart

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, shopping-cart

I would like to add a custom block next to each item displayed in the shopping cart, which has access to the properties of the specific product it has access to.

Since, this is a part of a plugin, I need to do so without hardcoding anything into core files, i.e. only through the use of `layout.xml`/event handlers. Any other way which does not involve modifying Magento files.

For example: adding a button which displays itself next to each item in the shopping cart, and performs an action on the SKU of the particular product it is displayed next to.

I will post a screenshot of what I mean shortly.

Just to be clear I do not want to override the existing block, I want to **"add"** to it

Comment: anyone have any working ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your module's layout xml file:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>custom/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>custom/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>custom/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

And then override the magento cart render template by copying `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` to `custom/cart/item/default.phtml`. Now you have access to the product by using `$_item->getProduct()` in your phtml.

Comment: but doesnt this involve changing core functionality, or can it be packed inside a plugin too?

Comment: In this case we are not changing any core files, what we are doing is just overriding the template with a new one. Also, Yes,  you can pack this in an extension by a adding the above xml to that modules layout file.

Comment: but since we are copying files from one location to another, and modifying the default.phtml file, if there are updates to magento, or other changes made to the default.phtml file in the original folder, wont there be clashes?

for instance if the user decides to hardcode stuff into the default.phtml file in the checkout/cart/item/default.phtml, but since our plugin is now using custom/cart/item/default.phtml, the changes wont show up now right?

Comment: also i guess we have to include the default.phtml file manually right?, what if the installers default.phtml file differs from the one i include inside the plugin?

Comment: The one in plugin will override installed default.html

Comment: but doesnt that mean that, if they have a modified default.phtml, when  ours overrides theirs, it will now show up on the cart then? 
E.G. a theme or the site owner has harcoded getchild() into the default.phtml, and ours obviously wont have that, so when it overrides theirs, that getchild() will be missing right?

Is there any way to just "add" or append to the file, and not replace it compeltely(overriding is essentially replacing by redirecting magento to our default.phtml instead of the original one")

Comment: I overrode it, but the styling is messed up, even though the conents are displaying as expected

Comment: Styling part you can correct. Please accept this as answer to help others with same isse

Comment: its not only the css, a lot of elements, such as the increase/decrease button next to the item quanity in cart is also missing